# Object Handling

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overriding

I want to have a list of objects that are linked by their base class.  So I will have a class that manages all the different flavors of objects but are uniformly stored in their base class form.  I want to be able to handle a test collision between two objects one being a sphere and the other a cube.  I would say call a function like so sphere->collisionTest(cube).  Using polymorphism I can call the collisionTest method and it will go to appropriate method in the sphere class but I need a way to identify/override which collisionTest method within the sphere class.  Parameter overriding a sphere.collisionTest(sphere) or sphere.collisionTest(cube).  Here is some example code of what I have tried.  Here when I call the collisionTest(object->getObject()) method I believe I should be getting the cube object and then it will parameter override and call the collisionTest(Cuboid *object) method.  Instead it calls the same collisionTest(Geom *object).

```
int main()
{
Geom *geomHandler1;// = new Geom();
Geom *geomHandler2;// = new Geom();

Sphere *sphereGeom = new Sphere();
Cuboid *cuboidGeom = new Cuboid();

geomHandler1 = (Geom*)sphereGeom;
geomHandler2 = (Geom*)cuboidGeom;

geomHandler1->collisionTest(geomHandler2);


return 0;
}



#include "Sphere.h"

void Sphere::collisionTest(Geom *object)
{
collisionTest(object->getObject());
}

void Sphere::collisionTest(Cuboid *object)
{

}

Sphere* Sphere::getObject()
{
Sphere *husk = new Sphere();
return husk;
}



#include "Cuboid.h"

void Cuboid::collisionTest(Geom *object)
{

}

void Cuboid::collisionTest(Sphere *object)
{

}

Cuboid* Cuboid::getObject()
{
Cuboid *husk = new Cuboid();
return husk;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this because only the collisionTest method that takes a Geom object can be overridden. Your Geom object has no idea what is a collision with a cube and that's why it's not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking about is known as "double dispatch", which Google. There's really no simple, clean way to do double dispatch in C++, unfortunately. The ordinary way is for each geometry type to return an enum giving its type; then you can just switch on the type enum returned by the object, static_cast it, and invoke the appropriate function.

Comment: yea that is what i was doing before but wanted a more elegant solution which is almost impossible to do im finding out.

Comment: There are solutions which a software architect might call "elegant". But they are not what a programmer would call "a good idea".

Answer (score 0):

Is that what u mean by the enumerated type?

```
void Sphere::collisionTest(Geom *object)
{
switch (object->getID())
{
    case SPHERE : sphCollTest((Sphere*)object);
    break;
    case CUBOID : cubCollTest((Cuboid*)object);
    break;

}
}
```